# Flutter versioning CI/CD with Fastlane and Github Actions

Tags: flutter, github-actions, fastlane

I have implemented the configuration for fastlane and github actions in my flutter project for iOS, with some custom actions for incrementing the version and build number.

```js
default_platform(:ios)

DEVELOPER_APP_ID = ENV['DEVELOPER_APP_ID']
DEVELOPER_APP_IDENTIFIER = ENV['DEVELOPER_APP_IDENTIFIER']
PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER = ENV['PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER']
TEMP_KEYCHAIN_USER = ENV['TEMP_KEYCHAIN_USER']
TEMP_KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD = ENV['TEMP_KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD']
Path = '/Users/*********'

def delete_temp_keychain(name)
  if File.exist? File.expand_path("~/Library/Keychains/#{name}-db")
    delete_keychain(
      name: name
    )
  end
end

def create_temp_keychain(name, password)
  print('name', name, 'password', password)
  create_keychain(
    name: name,
    password: password,
    unlock: false,
    timeout: 0
  )
end

def ensure_temp_keychain(name, password)
  delete_temp_keychain(name)
  create_temp_keychain(name, password)
end

def update_version(type)
  case type
  when 'major' then increment_version_number_in_xcodeproj(bump_type: 'major')
  when 'minor' then increment_version_number_in_xcodeproj(bump_type: 'minor')
  when 'patch' then increment_version_number_in_xcodeproj(bump_type: 'patch')
  else abort("Unknown version bump type: #{type}\nValid options: major, minor, patch.")
  end
end

platform :ios do
  lane :update_major do
    update_version('major')
    increment_build_number
  end
  lane :update_minor do
    update_version('minor')
    increment_build_number
  end
  lane :update_patch do
    # update_patch('patch')
    # increment_build_number
    
    script = 'perlscript.pl'
    latest
    exec("/usr/bin/perl #{script}")
    # perl -i -pe 's/^(version:\s+\d+\.\d+\.\d+\+)(\d+)$/$1.($2+1)/e' /Users/*******/Dev/******/pubspec.yaml")
 
  end

  
  lane :_release_candidate do
    keychain_name = TEMP_KEYCHAIN_USER
    keychain_password = TEMP_KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD
    # ensure_temp_keychain('fastlane_keychain_login', '!QA#ED4rf')
    ensure_temp_keychain(keychain_name, keychain_password)
    add_git_tag(
      grouping: 'fastlane-builds',
      includes_lane: true,
      prefix: 'v',
      build_number: get_build_number,
      postfix: "-RC#{get_build_number}"
    )

    push_to_git_remote # this will git-push the above newly created local git-tag
    # match(
    #   type: 'appstore',
    #   app_identifier: "#{DEVELOPER_APP_IDENTIFIER}",
    #   git_basic_authorization: Base64.strict_encode64(ENV['GIT_AUTHORIZATION']),
    #   readonly: true,
    #   keychain_name: keychain_name,
    #   keychain_password: keychain_password
    # )

    # gym(
    #   configuration: 'Release',
    #   workspace: 'Runner.xcworkspace',
    #   scheme: 'Runner',
    #   export_method: 'app-store',
    #   export_options: {
    #     provisioningProfiles: {
    #       DEVELOPER_APP_ID => PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER
    #     }
    #   }
    # )

    # pilot(
    #   apple_id: "#{DEVELOPER_APP_ID}",
    #   app_identifier: "#{DEVELOPER_APP_IDENTIFIER}",
    #   skip_waiting_for_build_processing: false,
    #   skip_submission: true,
    #   distribute_external: false,
    #   notify_external_testers: false,
    #   ipa: './Runner.ipa'
    # )

    delete_temp_keychain(keychain_name)
  end
end
```

as shown in the fastfile above I even tried to using **perl** to update the pubspec but I couldn't manage to pass the new value after incrementing it.

```js
#!/bin/bash
# set -e

# Find and increment the version number.

perl -i -pe 's/^(version:\s+\d+\.\d+\.\d+\+)(\d+)$/$1.($2+1)/e' /Users/******/Dev/*******/pubspec.yaml
```

I am facing a problem updating the incremented number in xcode using `increment_build_number` action from fastlane, to **pubspec.yaml** version and syncing the changed files from the github action to the main repo or to my local repo, since the incrementation is occuring by running the lane in the github action.

Comment: Hi, have you figured it out & would you mind sharing your Github Action

Comment: Hi, @Aristidios, no actually i didn't yet but i will proceed working on it soon.

Comment: @Aristidios, i found a way in the answer below !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found one way to update the incremented build version by adding this code to the yml file for GitHub actions after the incrementing job:

```
- uses: stefanzweifel/git-auto-commit-action@v4
  with:
    commit_message: Apply php-cs-fixer changes
```

where it auto commit and pushes the changes to the repo, and from that point a pull request can be created and voila, you have the changes locally again to be synced with the actions triggered before.

**++EDIT++**

you can check the full code in the github yml file, where i am triggering the script from the fastlane file based on keywords in the commit message:

```html
# cd.yml
name: CD



on:
  push:
    branches:
      - 'main'
      
jobs:
 deploy_ios:
    name: Deploy beta build to TestFlight
    runs-on: macos-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code from ref
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          ref: ${{ github.ref }}
      - name: Run Flutter tasks
        uses: subosito/flutter-action@v1
        with:
          flutter-version: '3.0.3'
      - run: flutter pub get
      - run: flutter build ios --release --no-codesign 
      - name: increment major
        if: "contains(github.event.head_commit.message, 'major')"
        uses: maierj/fastlane-action@v1.4.0
        with: 
          lane: update_major
          subdirectory: ios
      - name: increment minor
        if: "contains(github.event.head_commit.message, 'minor')"
        uses: maierj/fastlane-action@v1.4.0
        with: 
          lane: update_minor
          subdirectory: ios
      - name: increment patch
        if: "contains(github.event.head_commit.message, 'patch')"
        uses: maierj/fastlane-action@v1.4.0
        with: 
          lane: update_patch
          subdirectory: ios
      - name: Deploy iOS Beta to TestFlight via Fastlane
        uses: maierj/fastlane-action@v1.4.0
        with:
          lane: _release_candidate
          subdirectory: ios
      - uses: stefanzweifel/git-auto-commit-action@v4
        with:
          commit_message: Auto Commit

      
        env:
          APP_STORE_CONNECT_TEAM_ID: '${{ secrets.APP_STORE_CONNECT_TEAM_ID }}'
          DEVELOPER_APP_ID: '${{ secrets.DEVELOPER_APP_ID }}'
          DEVELOPER_APP_IDENTIFIER: '${{ secrets.DEVELOPER_APP_IDENTIFIER }}'
          DEVELOPER_PORTAL_TEAM_ID: '${{ secrets.DEVELOPER_PORTAL_TEAM_ID }}'
          FASTLANE_APPLE_ID: '${{ secrets.FASTLANE_APPLE_ID }}'
          FASTLANE_APPLE_APPLICATION_SPECIFIC_PASSWORD: '${{ secrets.FASTLANE_APPLE_APPLICATION_SPECIFIC_PASSWORD }}'
          MATCH_PASSWORD: '${{ secrets.MATCH_PASSWORD }}'
          GIT_AUTHORIZATION: '${{ secrets.GIT_AUTHORIZATION }}'
          PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER: '${{ secrets.PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER }}'
          TEMP_KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD: '${{ secrets.TEMP_KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD }}'
          TEMP_KEYCHAIN_USER: '${{ secrets.TEMP_KEYCHAIN_USER }}'
```

Comment: Really great ! Do you think you could put your full Github Action Code in your answer ?  @hasan : )

Comment: I can do that, as you see in the fastlane file above i am triggering the script from the github action based on a commit message, but i will edit my answer with the full code

Comment: thanks  you should definitely right a full article on CI-CD with Fastlane & Github